# How to handle async exceptions while calling DeleteDocumentAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Diving into CosmosDB and asybc calls I found myself in a bit of a problem. I am creating a web service call to delete a CosmosDB document but exception handling is acting up a bit, I assume is because the nature of the async call. Basically the exception is not bubbling up to the controller and the execution is jumping off causing the call to look successful when it is not.

How can I capture the exception being thrown by the DeleteDocumentAsync method so I can return the corresponding error to the calling client?

Thank you all in advance!

Controller code:

```
[HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid key)
        {
            ActionResult result;
            try
            {
               result = StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
               _repository.Delete<CodeKeyPairModel>(codeKeyPair);   
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Fatal error deleting record key", ex);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
</code>
```

Repository code

```
 public async void Delete<T>(T codeKeyPairModel) where T : CodeKeyPairModel
        {
            var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(cosmosDBId, collectionId, codeKeyPairModel.Id.ToString());
            var result = await cosmosDBClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentLink,
                    new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository needs to use `async Task` and not `async void`. The `async void` is why you can't capture the exception.

```
public async Task Delete<T>(T codeKeyPairModel) where T : CodeKeyPairModel {
    var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(cosmosDBId, collectionId, codeKeyPairModel.Id.ToString());
    var result = await cosmosDBClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentLink,
            new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an `async Task` or `async Task<T>` method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With `async void` methods, there is no `Task` object, so any exceptions thrown out of an `async void` method will be raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the `async void` method started.

Secondly your API code is doing a Fire and Forget pattern by not awaiting the Task in `Delete`. You need to `await _respository.Delete`.

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid key)
{
    ActionResult result;
    try
    {
       result = StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
       await _repository.Delete<CodeKeyPairModel>(codeKeyPair);   
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Fatal error deleting record key", ex);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed my answer and will edit the necessary parts into yours

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it. now to the next issue. I've implemented 2 repositories (one for in-memory and one for CosmosDB)  based on one Interface. The challenge now is to get them back to work together once I changed the Interface signature, but that is a complete separate problem. Thanks!